# how to animate this radial gradient shifting corner to corner and so on

Tags: html, animation, svg

So I have this svg

```html
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" width="100%">
          <defs>
            <radialGradient id="0" gradientTransform="translate(-1 0) scale(2, 2)">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(0, 95, 89)"/>
              <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)"/>
              <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform" type="translate" values="-1 0;-1 -1;0 -1;0 0;-1 0" type="scale" values="2, 2;2, 2;2, 2;2, 2" dur="5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            </radialGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect fill="url(#0)" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        </svg>
```

My idea is want to make the gradient is shifting from top-left corner to top-right corner..and so on, and it continue looping. instead of resulting that, my svg going so weird. that the animation coming from the top.

when I remove the animation, the gradient is normal from what I am expected, the gradient placed at top-left corner.

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" width="100%">
              <defs>
                <radialGradient id="0" gradientTransform="translate(-1 -1) scale(2, 2)">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(0, 95, 89, 0.4)"/>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)"/> 
                </radialGradient>
              </defs>
              <rect fill="url(#0)" height="100%" width="100%"/>
            </svg>
```

can you help me to achieve that, please. Thank you

Comment: you really need one animateTransform with values instead of from/to so that all the transforms don't run at once.

Comment: @RobertLongson it's still resulting weird animation. its like the animation runs outside my div. here is my value `values="-1 0;-1 -1;0 -1;0 0;-1 0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Since you'll use `gradientTransform` for animation, things get easier if you don't use it for the basic gradient itself. In this case, we can use `cx`, `cy` and `r` to place the gradient in the top left corner.
2. As a bonus, your animation coordinates also get easier to work with: `0 0` is the top left corner and `1 1` is bottom right.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="0" cx="0" cy="0" r="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(0, 195, 189)"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)"/>
            <animateTransform attributeName="gradientTransform" type="translate" values="0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1; 0 0;" 
                              dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#0)" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```